# Parse whole html(avg. size 20MB) through URL using JSOUP

Tags: java, jsoup, html-parsing, html-parser

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("some html url").get();
Elements catelist=  document.select("TEXT");
```

above code is not giving full html.

Comment: Here's a guess.  The parser is taking too long, and the server you are fetching from is timing out the response transmission.  Try downloading to a local file and then parsing that.

Answer (score 3):

The max body size is limited to 1MB by default. You can change that default value using `maxBodySize(int)` :

```
//for example to set the max body size to 20 MB
Document document = Jsoup.connect(some html url).timeout(0).maxBodySize(1024*1024*20).get();

//or set it to 0 to have an unlimited size
Document document = Jsoup.connect(some html url).timeout(0).maxBodySize(0).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want html code of full page 
Then use:

```
document.html();
```

If you want html code of particular tag
Then use:

```
catelist.html();
```